# Mathematical term for the on/off gradient functions in MRI imaging

Tags: terminology, signal-processing, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

The slice selection gradients, as well as the phase and frequency, in MRI imaging are traditionally represented by on/off box or rectangular symbols:

[image]

[or](http://mriquestions.com/what-is-fsetse.html)

[image]

My question is what is the mathematical name for these functions - it would be the equivalent of multiple rectangle functions, periodic or not. For example:

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: that is a square wave.

Comment: @JEB Right! [Here it is](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareWave.html). Thank you.

Comment: @JEB Would "step function" be a more generic name to include all possible arrangements of rectangle / box functions - periodic and non periodic?

Comment: the "Heaviside Step Function" is different. What you drew is a square wave--I'm sure it's an option on your synth: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2uB4nKzGlg

Answer (score 0):

They are usually simply called trapezoidal waveforms or trapezoidal gradients. The vertical edges are not possible, the maximum change in gradient strength with respect to time (dG/dt) is called the slew rate. In modern MRI systems it is on the order of 200 mT/m/ms

Comment: Do you have any link? Are any of these on/off oscillating functions called "trapezoidal" regardless of the context?

Comment: I cannot tell you about other contexts. I have only seen these waveforms in the context of MRI gradients. Here is an example in the context of reducing peripheral nerve stimulation:  https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/mrm.1910320213

Comment: I like your answer a lot because of your comment on the fact that the slew rate prevents a completely square morphology in real life. However, I think that the right answer just came in a comment to the OP: "square wave."

Comment: Yes, good point. The waves as drawn are square waves. Square waves are not used for the gradients in MRI due to hardware limitations, but in that sense I didn’t answer the question asked but rather changed the question and answered that. I hope that is ok.